# Operatic composition techniques

Tags: songwriting, opera

In [this interview](https://youtu.be/NjR2AsAjHOw?t=1524), one of my favorite composers (and my favorite male vocalist)--Rufus Wainwright--explains that he has "leaned on" opera for various tricks which he has applied to his pop, piano-oriented songwriting.  Do any opera fans (familiar with his music or not) have any idea which aspects of opera composition he might be referring to?

Update:

I would like to add that one his genre's on wikipedia include "operatic pop" and "baroque pop" . . . not sure what those are.

Here's a sentence on his interest in opera:

> Wainwright became interested in opera during his adolescent years,
> and the genre strongly influences his music. (For instance, the song
> "Barcelona" features lyrics from the libretto of Giuseppe Verdi's
> opera, Macbeth.) During this time, he became interested in Édith Piaf,
> Al Jolson, and Judy Garland. As a youth he trained at Interlochen Arts
> Camp, studying classical music.[16]

Comment: Please name the composer.  If the interview doesn't elaborate on this topic, then the link to the video isn't helpful.

Comment: I'm not getting much from that interview except that Wainwright feels a bit out of his depth running with the 'classical' guys.   No need to.  He writes good songs, and his opera writing will develop.